# Será que "if condição 1" e "if condição 2" aninhados equivalem a "if condição 1 && condição 2"?

Tags: if, lógica, condição, booleano, álgebra-booleana

Será que o seguinte trecho:

```
if (condição1) {
    if (condição2) {
        ...
    }
} else {
    assert(!condição1);
    ...
}
```

é equivalente a:

```
if (condição1 && condição2) {
    ...
} else {
    assert(!condição1);
    ...
}
```

?

Sempre achei que sim, e até simplificava meus `if`s de acordo, mas acabei de descobrir que não (talvez tenha descoberto antes, mas havia esquecido).

Pois se o `else` esperar (*asserts*) que a condição 1 seja falsa (por exemplo, se condição 1 for `x == null`, e portanto o `assert` for um `assert(x != null);`, e `x` tiver sido inicializada com um valor não-nulo antes do `if`) então no primeiro caso o `assert` é validado, e no segundo não (***obs.: esta sub-conclusão está errada, vide edição***).

No segundo caso é possível entrar no `else` sendo a condição 1 verdadeira e a 2 falsa.

Se não houver `else` concordo que ficam equivalentes, mas qualquer `else` ou `else if` embaixo complica tudo.

A alteração da lógica do primeiro if afeta o else mais abaixo.

Não tem nada a ver com & bitwise e nem com curto-circuito de operadores, que neste caso não está sendo aplicado.

Só documentando. Comentários?

**EDIT:** O meu segundo parágrafo após os exemplos está errado em termos de lógica. Mas a conclusão geral de que as duas situações não são equivalentes ainda vale, pois conforme a combinação de verdadeiro e falso das duas condições pode-se entrar no else ou não, a depender de qual exemplo está sendo considerado. Por exemplo, conforme explicado no terceiro parágrafo, se a condição 1 for verdadeira e a 2 falsa então no primeiro caso não vai entrar no else e no segundo sim.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você utiliza um `if(condicao1 is null && condicao2 is null)`, o `&&` torna obrigatório que as duas condições sejam verdadeiras, quando você utiliza um if aninhado como abaixo, se a condição 2 for falsa, não vai cair no else que pertence ao primeiro if, nesse caso ele simplesmente finaliza a operação.

No EXEMPLO 1 o retorno é "Não executou a primeira condição".

```
string condicao1 = null;
string condicao2 = null;

---------- EXEMPLO 1 ----------

if(!(condicao1 is null && condicao2 is null))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entrou aqui e executou alguma operação");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Não executou a primeira condição");
}
```

No EXEMPLO 2 o retorno é "Entrou aqui e executou a PRIMEIRA condição".
Nesse caso, ele checa a segunda condição, porém se ela não é verdadeira pula a condição2 e segue para realizar outras operações.

```
---------- EXEMPLO 2 ----------

string condicao1 = null;
string condicao2 = null;

if(condicao1 is null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Entrou aqui e executou a PRIMEIRA condição");
    
    if(!(condicao2 is null))
        Console.WriteLine("Entrou aqui e executou a SEGUNDA condição");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Não executou a primeira condição");
}
```

Comment: Não é equivalente ao que eu escrevi, tem uma negação no primeiro caso.

Comment: A negação é um exemplo, a lógica segue a mesma, você poderia utilizar um if(condicao1 != null && condicao2 != null), que o final é o mesmo, a condição é false.